# What backup strategies to use with Bitlocker?

Tags: windows, backup, bitlocker

I'm looking at using Bitlocker on a new laptop.  I have been using Acronis for full image backups; it would take me way too much time to reinstall and configure from scratch in the event of a stolen laptop.   I would like to do periodic full system backups with daily incremental backups.

Acronis True Image treats Bitlocker images as black boxes; a backup is equal in size to the entire hard drive volume.  An incremental backup of a Bitlocker image results again in a backup equal to the size of the entire hard drive.

Vista's "Complete PC Backup and Restore" is a bit clumsy in that it is difficult to restore the system to new hardware for the case of a lost / stolen laptop.

Does Windows 7 support Bitlocker using Complete PC Backup and Restore, and restore to replacement hardware?

How can incremental backups be performed with Bitlocker?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that BitLocker provides full-volume encryption. You can easily use an online-based backup tool like Mozy or Carbonite, which will read the files from disk (decrypting them in the process) and then back them up to a separate cloud-based repository. These solutions typically provide their own encryption implementation. While you lose a bit of the bare-metal-restore capability of the Acronis solution, this may still be a viable alternative that's less expensive than deploying WHS.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for Windows 7, but I am sure some Googling would off you some answers about that.

As for how to backup your current situation, you have a couple of options - Use Acronis as you have been, but do [sector-by-sector](http://kb.acronis.com/content/1543) image backups, which will work in the event of a restore, but as you mentioned will be large.  You can deal with the built-in Vista features, or, buy/build a [Windows Home Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/windowshomeserver/default.mspx), which supports backing up Bitlocker encrypted drives.

Short answer, I think for your purposes (no access to enterprise class backup solutions), unless you are willing to set up a server at home, or deal with the large size of the acrnois images, you are pretty much limited to the built in tools Vista has.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, the default "system image" function in Windows 7, does support bitlocker transparently. The backed up image will be unencrypted automatically.

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b34b4da-b1e2-4038-8d6d-192f973cadea/using-system-image-with-a-bitlocker-system-drive)

Alternatively, using third-party software, it's generally recommended to decrypt first before imaging even though it might take some time. This is because imaging a bitlockered drive is usually not supported.

[Source 2](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/755032-how-to-clone-a-bitlocker-encrypted-hdd)